# Printing seed used by the model

Tags: netlogo

How can I see (print) the seed that my model uses to generate randomness?
I would like to specify the seed number when presenting the findings.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, NetLogo does not provide access to the state of the random number generator.  It is a good practice to report the seed.  Ordinarily one achieves this by setting it explicitly.  E.g., in setup, one can include `random-seed behaviorspace-run-number`, so that each run uses a different seed. You can then include the run number in your report. If you don't want to set your own seed, you will still have to create it and store it.  E.g., create a `run-seed` global, and then during setup `set run-seed new-seed random-seed run-seed`.

Comment: Thank you. Just a curiosity. I was trying a code I found in the book Agent_Zero to set the seed manually during the setup. If I combine this code to your code I obtain two different seeds. For example, I input "3" with the Agent_Zero code and when I input "show run-seed" I obtain some random number (eg 603859385, -1023698373 etc.). I think I am doing some confusion, one of the two numbers maybe is not the seed?

Comment: This is the code:  
`to use-new-seed
  let my-seed new-seed
  output-print word "Generated seed: " my-seed
  random-seed my-seed
end

to use-seed-from-user
  let my-seed read-from-string user-input "Enter a random seed (an integer):"
  output-print word "User-entered seed: " my-seed
  random-seed my-seed
end`